# HTML, Align a File browser and a submit button

Tags: html

I'm building a simple Web UI for an embedded system.

I have a couple of buttons to upload a file to the server, the code of the buttons is the following

```css
.button {
  background-color: #009999;
  border: 0.5px solid #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #197276;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<td style="width: 20%; vertical-align:top; background-color:#FFFFFF;">
  <form action="cgi-bin/upload.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="button" type="file" name="file">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
</td>
```

The problem that I noticed is that the file buttons is always slightly bigger than the submit button.

Is there a way to align them? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

[image: output]

EDIT:

After trying Yasaman Mansouri (thanks) suggestion (overflow: hidden) i get the follwing output (on the right).

It's much better but still not aligned with the other button.

[image: test with overlflow]

Answer (score 0):

you can hide your form overflow

```css
.button {
  background-color:#009999;
  border:0.5px solid #F0F0F0;
  border-radius:0px;
  color:white;
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  width:100%;
  padding:4px 4px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #197276;
  text-align:left;
}

form{
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<td style="width: 20%; vertical-align:top; background-color:#FFFFFF;">                             
    <form action="cgi-bin/upload.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                
          <input class="button" type="file" name="file" >
          <input class="button" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload">
          </p>
    </form>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, it's still a little misaligned, i edited the post with the new look.

Answer (score 0):

We got it answered on Reddit, by adding "box-sizing:border-box;" to the button css
the alignment is OK.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

```
.button {
  background-color: #009999;
  border: 0.5px solid #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #197276;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Thanks!